# Using adsense code inside php code

Tags: php, adsense

Is this legal to use adsense code inside php tags like this and does this affect the behavior of the ad?

```
<?php function myfn(){

php code here ?>
 <script  async='async' src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
     <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="<?php echo $ad_client; ?>"
     data-ad-slot="<?php echo $ad_slot; ?>"></ins>
     <script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
 <?php }?>
```

and call this function wherever I want the ad.

Comment: Adsense [Ad placement policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/topic/1271508?hl=en&ref_topic=1261918)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adsense/Google doesn't care what's going on in your PHP code and how exactly ad block code gets in the HTML code of the page, so as long as this function works and you are not breaking any other Adsense rules such as appropriate content and no more than three ad blocks per page - you should be fine.

The suggestion if I may - use responsive ad units, so you can use your ad block/function without warring about of the size of the container. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en

Comment: @Ahmed if you are satisfied with the answer please consider accepting it. Thanks!